# Problem with spacy: error: bad escape \p at position 257

Tags: python, r, spacy, reticulate

I'm getting the error

```
`Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : error: bad escape \p at position 257 `
```

running a python code with R through the use of "reticulate" package.

The issue comes up while executing the row:

```
spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
```

I already checked with `spacy validate` that I have a version of spacy (v2.0.18) that agrees with the language model version (2.0.0).

Of course the code runs fine if executed with python.

Comment: So, `python -m spacy validate` (as suggested [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3544)) does not help, right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, it doesn't help as I said

Comment: Is `en_core_web_lg` definitely installed in the same python environment that you are using to run `reticulate`? I normally set up a specific environment in conda and then use the `reticulate::use_condaenv()` function to make sure the correct packages are available.

Comment: @meenaparam Yes, it is in the same environment

Comment: @meenaparam if I write  `repl_python()` and then  `import spacy` it runs. If I try to load the language model with  `spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')` it returns the error.

Comment: So the error doesn't happen in the REPL, only outside of the REPL?

Answer (score 1):

You should install the latest version of language model through the following command

```
!pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0.tar.gz
```

This should solve the error

Comment: You solved my problem!